# How to retrieve the original train/test split for MNIST when using `sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata` to retrieve the data?

Tags: scikit-learn

I used `sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata` to download the MNIST data set, and then used the data to train some interesting variants of canonical machine learning algorithms. I have now been asked to confirm my findings using the original train/test split as on [Yann LeCuns MNIST webpage](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Is there a way to retrieve the original train/test split using `sklearn` or do I have to re-import the data from another source?